# ApacheでHTTPリクエストの方がHTTPSリクエストより遅くなることはあるでしょうか？

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2 上に Amazon Linux 2 を構築し、その上でApache2.4＋PHP8.0（mod_php）を動作させています。
yumでインストールしたApacheであり、mpmはpreforkで動作しています。
自己証明書を作成しSSLでのリクエストも応答できるようにしました。

この時、自分のPCからHTTP経由でChrome開発者ツールでキャッシュ無効としてアクセスしたあるphpページ（システムのログインページ）表示の時間が35秒かかりました。
ある事情により子プロセス数を1としているため、時間がかかることは承知の上です。

ですが、この時、HTTPSで同じくChrome開発者ツールでキャッシュ無効として同じURLにアクセス（違うのプロトコルのみ）すると、3.96秒で表示されます。

順番を逆にしても何度か繰り返しても状況は変わりません。
何が原因か予測がつきますか？

ちなみに開発者ツールのネットワークタブで見ると一番時間がかかっているのはjquery.cookie.min.jsで、これ一つに35秒かかっています。サーバ内のアクセスlog上では208μsでレスポンスしているらしいです。他にも時間がかかっているファイルはありますが、jsやcssといった静的ファイルのみです

Comment: 予想する暇があったら測りまくって切り分けましょう。再現する最小限のコードセットが分かってなお自分で原因が分からない場合に聞くくらいで十分です。